# Pass JavaScript variable to PHP and return PHP result to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass a JavaScript variable to a PHP file using AJAX and then return the result of the PHP file back to a JavaScript variable.

For passing the JavaScript variable to the PHP file I would assume it was something like [how to use ajax to assign javascript variable to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269465/how-to-use-ajax-to-assign-javascript-variable-to-php-variable)

My JavaScript variable will be used to query a MySQL database, I then need the PHP to return a value from the database back to a JavaScript variable.

I know you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Quantity = parseInt(str);
  $("#ajaxResult").load($.ajax({url:"yourphp.php",type:"POST",async:false,data:{quantity:Quantity}}););
});
```

To set the result of the PHP file to show in an HTML element with the id `ajaxResult`

But how would I set a variable to the result, maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      Quantity = parseInt(str);
      var result = $.load($.ajax({url:"yourphp.php",type:"POST",async:false,data:{quantity:Quantity}}););
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the `success` property of `$.ajax`?

```
returnVariable = NULL;
$.ajax({
  url:"yourphp.php",
  type:"POST",
  async:false,
  data:{quantity:Quantity},
  success:function(d){
    returnVariable = d;
  }
});
```

You can also achieve it using `.done()`:

```
$.ajax({
  //Properties
}).done(function(d){
  returnVariable = d;
});
```

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous, so the value will be assigned after the http call and return - which could take seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of argument passed to your success handler:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourURL.com",
  data: jsonString,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    var myNewJSVar = data;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use $.post(); instead...

In your case you can use:

```
$.post('url-to-post', {'var-name':'var-value'}, function(data) {
    // here 'data' has the data returned by your .php file
});
```

Here the documentation for $.post() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite store the result to the ajax query in a global variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var quantity = parseInt(str);
  var result = null;
  $.ajax({url:"yourphp.php",
     type:"POST",
     async:false,
     data:quantity,
     success: function(data) { 
        result = data; 
     }
  });
});
```

The ajax call is asynchronous, so the value will be assigned after the http call and return - which could take seconds. The success callback will be run once the http call has a result from the server. Usually the code to update your html page will be run here maybe `$('resultDiv').html(data);`. This is what the `.load()` call does in your previous post.

Jquery provides lots of shortcut methods like `.post()`, `.load()`, all the same effects can be achieved using `.ajax()` although it will involve more typing!